# Use variable provided; else derive and use

Tags: bash, shell-script

Trying to achieve the following using a script with no luck

If value of variable is provided use it for further steps, else derive value executing a script which writes to a file and use it for further steps

```
#!/bin/bash
if [[ -z "$VER" ]] then
echo "VER not provided; Deriving value from INT"
./get_ver.rb > VER      
endif
echo "VER=$VER" > VER
```

Comment: Instead of `./get_ver.rb > VER` change it to `VER=$(./get_ver.rb)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script contains multiple syntax errors.

This is a fixed version:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [[ -z "$VER" ]]; then
  echo "VER not provided; Deriving value from INT"
  VER="$( ./get_ver.rb )"
fi
echo "VER=$VER" >VER
```

Notice the `;` before `then` and `fi` to end the `if`-statement.

To store the output of a command in a variable, use `$(...)` as above.

Use [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) to check your shell scripts.

Comment: Thanks @Kusalananda - that works - thanks for the tip about ShellCheck

Answer (score 4):

A couple of common idioms (in any POSIX shell, not just `bash`, so is safe to use in `sh` scripts as well):

```
VER=${VER-$(./get_ver.rb)}
```

Or:

```
: "${VER=$(./get_ver.rb)}"
```

`${VER-value}` expands to the content of `$VER` if `$VER` is set (even to the empty value), and to `value` otherwise.

`${VER=value}`: same except that `value` is also assigned to `$VER` if `$VER` was previously unset.

Note that your `[[ -z $VER ]]` checks whether the content of `$VER` is empty or not, not if `$VER` is set. If `$VER` is set, but to an empty value, it will still return true. You can do `[ -z "${VER+yes}" ]` (here using the `[` standard command instead of that `[[...]]` Korn construct, though you could also do it with `[[...]]`) to check if `$VER` is set. Another less obvious way would be with `${VER+:} false`.